# In RSA or Assymetric Encryption, What EXACTLY is the purpose of the Private key? Do both hosts send their private key to each other?

Tags: networking, security, encryption, rsa, decryption

First, let me know if i got anything wrong.

The whole private and public key concept confuses me to no end. From what I know, basically RSA uses both public and private key. Public keys are PUBLICLY unknown, meaning everyone can get their hands on it.

So this begs the question of what the purpose of the private key.. do private keys unique to each hosts? is it fixed or dynamically generated? does the private key get sent across the network to decrypt the data? if this was the case, why can't MITM who completely eavesdrops the connection stole/get/obtain the private keys?

So many questions. I've been rereading the previous similar questions but instead of the complex math, I only really want to know the basic concept.

Thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: public keys write messages that can be read only by people with the private key. the private key can read messages. so you download my public key, so you can send me a message that only I can read, using my private key.  when I send you a message back, I download your public key, encrypt the message to you, and sign it with my private key, so that you know it came from me, and only you can read it.

Answer (score 3):

> does the private key get sent across the network to decrypt the data? if this was the case, why can't MITM who completely eavesdrops the connection stole/get/obtain the private keys?

It is not the case, and it's even literally the point of asymmetric encryption that the participants do not ever need to send their private keys to each other.

(For example, a TLS server or an SSH host presents only its public key and a *proof* of having the private key – almost always a digital signature which is computed in such a way that the public key can be used to verify it.)

Public and private keys always come in pairs (usually the private key is generated first, then a public key is *derived* from that), and what makes it 'asymmetric' is that that data encrypted with the public key cannot be decrypted with the same public key again; it is only decryptable with the corresponding private key.

So if you're talking about encryption, the overall flow looks roughly like this:

0. Recipient R has a public/private key pair. Sender S has no keys, only some data to send.
1. Recipient R provides only their public key to sender S.
2. Sender S encrypts data with R's public key and sends that to R.
3. R uses their own private key to decrypt the received data.

---

Keep in mind though that data encryption is not the main use of asymmetric cryptography. Sure, it has its uses, but the overwhelming majority of asymmetric crypto is found in 1) digital signatures and 2) key exchange.

(A digital signature is asymmetric *cryptography*, but not asymmetric *encryption*. True, the algorithm for creating RSA digital signatures looks similar to the one used for RSA encryption – to the point that some people say "signing is backwards encryption" – but that's very misleading.)

With digital signatures, it's the opposite: once the sender signs something using their own private key, it is enough for recipients to have the corresponding public key to be able to verify the signature; there's no need to send the private key anywhere at all. (Again, that's why it's called 'asymmetric' cryptography.)

Signatures is how TLS certificates and SSH keys work most of the time; the SSH server sends you a temporary signature to prove that it owns its 'host' private key, then your client sends it another signature to prove that you own your id_rsa private key. (Encryption-based schemes were used for this purpose in the past, but not anymore; signature schemes are more versatile.)

---

You asked about 'hosts' sending their RSA keys to each other for encryption, and about whether those keys are fixed or dynamic. In most cases (assuming you meant typical protocols such as TLS or SSH), the answer is "None of the above" because those protocols *do not use* RSA to encrypt the connection in the first place.

What happens instead, in TLS and SSH both, is that a *key exchange* algorithm is used to allow both hosts create a symmetric key somehow, and that key is then used with a traditional symmetric algorithm such as AES.

Key exchange *can* be implemented using ordinary asymmetric encryption (e.g. server sends public key, client encrypts symmetric key with public key) but in practice very rarely is; both TLS and SSH prefer using a dedicated "key exchange algorithm" (almost always a variant of the Diffie-Hellman algorithm) that allows both hosts to generate a key without actually sending it to each other.

So in practice there are several different kinds of keys involved and they have different lifetimes:

- If the server has a certificate like in TLS (or a 'host key' like SSH), then that certificate has a fixed keypair, and this keypair is almost always used for signing, not for encryption.
- If Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange is used to establish encryption, then both hosts *usually* generate fresh DH keys every time.
- The temporary symmetric key used for actual encryption (AES) is, of course, dynamically generated.
- Finally, if the *client* has a certificate (like user keypairs in SSH), that's also fixed, and again is typically used only to sign data, not to encrypt it.

(Of course, all of this varies greatly between protocols and even protocol versions, e.g. SSHv1 did use temporary RSA keys whereas SSLv3 did support using fixed DH keys, and sometimes the certificate's key was used for encryption instead of DH, and so on...)